# Azure App Service Custom Hostnames

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

We're hosting our application on Azure and need to add a sub domain in the custom hostname section. We need to do this dynamically so needs to be done at run time.

I've tried using the Azure management rest API but can't seem to find the app when making any call.

Whats the best way to add a custom header to an app service with out using the Azure portal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just add `*.example.com`? Wildcard subdomains are supported in App Service.

Comment: Its a SaaS application so the wild card already points to an external landing page and mapped sub domains need to point to another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the API docs they had a call that did what we needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatehostnamebinding

Answer (score 1):

You could place an API Management in front of you app and use the "[Set HTTP header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader)" transformation policy to add a custom header to the request:

> Assigns a value to an existing response and/or request header or adds
>   a new response and/or request header